# How to upload to FTP from Travis CI

Tags: curl, ftp, gruntjs, travis-ci

I need to upload all the files in the Travis root directory to an FTP server after my build steps are completed. [Travis CI's documentation for custom deployment](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/custom/) suggests using curl to send the files. Unfortunately curl FTP upload doesn't support globing, which makes a large amount of files practically impossible.

How can I make sure my whole directory, including all files and subdirs, are uploaded to FTP?

Is there an elegant way to do this or is it better to rely on tools like grunt for uploading to FTP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use the find command to add everything except for specific folders.
2. Add the environment variables `SFTP_USER` and `SFTP_PASSWORD` in the Settings menu.

This is my yml:

```
language: node_js
after_success:
- find . -type d \( -path "./.*" -o -path "./node_modules" \) -prune -o -name "*" -print -exec curl --ftp-create-dirs -T {} ftp://your.server.com/dir/ --user ${SFTP_USER}:${SFTP_PASSWORD} \;
```

Answer (score 3):

The Travis doc says only that you should do this kind of stuffs in the `after_success:` section. The specified command is just an example.

So, do what you want from your computer, then put the sequence of commands that you used in the `after_success:` section.

In your case, creating an archive (with `tar`) and then uploading it (with `curl` or directly with `ftp`) should work, if I correctly understood your needs.

Comment: @stephanlindauer : Please, let me know if my answer helped you, or if you need more help.

Comment: thanks for your answer. what i actually need is a way of uploading multiple files. if i just upload a tar then  have the problem of not being able to trigger uncompressing that tar from my build job. the way i do things now is to just use grunt to upload all files to my ftp server.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the below link will help. Its about FTP deployment in node_js app.

[Travis build with nodejs en custom ftp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30692340/travis-build-with-nodejs-en-custom-ftp/33616519#33616519)