# Travis build with nodejs en custom ftp

Tags: continuous-integration, travis-ci

I m trying to use travis CI with nodejs and I m facing a problem like this one.

What I want here, is only to use ftp to upload my file, not to run any command.

```
No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)
```

I dont know what is the problem actually... Here's my travis.yml file :

```
env:
  global:
    - "FTP_USER=xxx"
    - "FTP_PASSWORD=xxx"
after_success:
    "curl --ftp-create-dirs -T uploadfilename -u $FTP_USER:$FTP_PASSWORD ftp://xxxx.fr/www/mochatest"
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced similar scenario when I decided to use Travis-CI with HTML+JS app. I finally ended up deployment from my package.json file via "posttest" section. I wrote some code which uses ftp-deploy npm module to upload the files. Test repository [here](https://github.com/joymon/travis-ci-test).